# magento 2 -how to show date time filter in sales order grid?

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

In magento 2 sales order grid default date purchase filter is there, but i want to filter with date and time both. please help me how to do.

I tried like below but i didn't get any solution.

Thanks

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento_Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Date">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="timezone" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM d</item>
    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
</argument>
</column>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in dateFormat item. Use  below code this will work for you.

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="timezone" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM dd, YYYY, H:mm:ss A</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one instead

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
  <settings>
    <filter>dateRange</filter>
    <dataType>date</dataType>
    <label translate="true">Created</label>
  </settings>
</column>
```